# Loading Python libraries in SQL Server is slow

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am using Python to do calculations that are not available in SQL Server.

In Jupyter Notebooks the calculation is done quite fast (with a csv as source), but in SQL Server, a single calculation takes 3 seconds. As I have thousands of calculations, this is much to slow.

Below is my code for the stored procedure that I feed my data, which is a table of wavelengths and interpolated data.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_PolynomeSecondDegree] 
    @ToBeProcessed PolynomeRegressionSource READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##DataStart') IS NOT NULL 
        DROP TABLE ##DataStart

    SELECT * 
    INTO ##DataStart 
    FROM @ToBeProcessed 

    EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
                @language = N'Python',
                @script=N'

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

X = InputDataSet[["WaveLength"]]
y = InputDataSet.InterPol
pre_process = PolynomialFeatures(degree = 2)
X_poly = pre_process.fit_transform(X)
pr_model = LinearRegression()
pr_model.fit(X_poly, y)
theta0 = pr_model.intercept_
_, theta1, theta2 = pr_model.coef_

OutputDataSet = pd.DataFrame({''a'':[theta0], ''b'':[theta1], ''c'':[theta2]} )
',
    @input_data_1 = N'SELECT * from ##DataStart'
    WITH RESULT SETS (( a float, b float, c float))

END
```

After some elimination, I noticed that if it is a 'normal' script without the import of sklearn, it is fast, but as soon as the import is added, it takes a long time.

Is there a way to load these libraries permanently or before I start these calculations in order to make it faster?

Or does this code make no sense and is there a much better (faster) way to handle this?

Thanks in advance,

Zeger

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefix is reserved by Microsoft and should **not** be used for User Procedures.

Comment: What does `a single calculation` mean? Against how much data? Your code is writing data into a new temporary table, which means this is definitely going to take some time, especially if there are a lot of rows. Have you tried running the same script against an *existing* table? Or using a better mechanism than a TVP and `SELECT INTO` to import data? `BULK INSERT` or `bcp` are a *lot* faster. If the data comes from a file, it would be faster to load the file in Python instead of going through a TVP

Comment: Check the answers to [this similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/246998/how-to-pass-a-table-valued-parameter-to-sp-execute-external-script). `input_data_1` can't receive a TVP but it *can* receive a data string. Instead of a TVP you can send the data as a string to the stored procedure, pass it to the Python script and have the script parse the data. You gain nothing by storing the data into a temporary string right now. You aren't querying that data, just loading it. You aren't using any indexes

Comment: A single calculation means a polynome calculation of between 200 and 500 data points. The reason I put it in a temp table was due to the TVP issue

Comment: When the procedure is run with a script that doesn't do anything and reads a table with only 2 lines, it still takes 2 seconds to run. The code used is `EXECUTE sp_execute_external_script 
 @language = N'Python',
@script=N'

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

OutputDataSet = pd.DataFrame({''a'':[0], ''b'':[1], ''c'':[2]} )
',
 @input_data_1 = N'select cast(PixelWavelenght as float) from Devices'
 WITH RESULT SETS (( a float, b float, c float))`